# Webrtc video call and audio call is not working on different network

Tags: ios, webrtc, call

I am working on video calling app and have implemented video and audio call with the help of webrtc-lib framework. So recently I got an issue that my video call and audio call is not working if my web (it is from where call is initiate) and app is on different network whereas in same network it is working fine. I know that we required turn and stun server for making call in webrtc and I am using third party "Metered" free servers for that purpose and also verify that these servers are working fine and generating proper ice candidates so I don't know what exactly is causing the issue. I have also test the same scenario with android app and it is working for them so I don't know if apple device is having some sort of security for not sharing ip address through stun and turn servers.

Note: I have faced one more weird scenario in which if I am testing my app in debug mode i.e with cable attached with mac (doesn't matter if it is attached with xcode) then call is working with different network also so this makes things more complicates as why it is working like this. Is it making some sort of network/connection through cable ?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

This is how i am initiating my webrtc connection.

```
required init(iceServers: [String], username:String, password: String) {
    let config = RTCConfiguration()
    config.iceServers = [RTCIceServer(urlStrings: iceServers, username: username, credential: password)]
    
    // Unified plan is more superior than planB
    config.sdpSemantics = .unifiedPlan
    
    // gatherContinually will let WebRTC to listen to any network changes and send any new candidates to the other client
    config.continualGatheringPolicy = .gatherContinually
    
    // Define media constraints. DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement is required to be true to be able to connect with web browsers.
    
    let constraints = RTCMediaConstraints(mandatoryConstraints:nil,
                                          optionalConstraints: ["DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement":kRTCMediaConstraintsValueTrue])
    
    let peerConnection = WebRTCClient.factory.peerConnection(with: config, constraints: constraints, delegate: nil)
    
    self.peerConnection = peerConnection!
    super.init()
    self.createMediaSenders()
    self.configureAudioSession()
    self.peerConnection.delegate = self
}
```